# Set text on ONLY left and ONLY right side of console

Tags: c

Lets say i have simple function to print text. (school homework its like chat with professor server)

```
// a) This should be right
    while (recvbuf[i] != '\n') {
            printf("%c", recvbuf[i]);
            i++;
        };

// b) This should be left
printf("I am text");
```

But "a)" can be only on right side cant be on left and "b)" can be only on left side cant be on right.

How can i do it? Thanks for any help.

// console window is of exactly size 24*80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For printing on left side of the terminal, you can simply use a print function like `printf` or `puts`.

For printing on right side of the terminal, you can use printf padding like that :

```
printf("%+80s\n", text);
```

You can see [printf man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) for more information on format option